# SQL using result from select from clause to join another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a legacy app, I am still learning SQL and would consider my SQL knowledge as beginner.

I have 2 tables, one is a receipt type structure containing receipt no, a docket number (plus other info regarding total etc) and a car rego number.

there are the potential for multiple receipts for a car ie multiple matches on rego number

The second has a listing of the items related to that receipt (description, partno, time) each of the items are related by docketnumber - the "registerhistory"

multiple items appear as multiple rows (with same docketnumber) in the "registerhistory" and also  items of the same type are not stored as a qty but as duplicated rows in the table with the same docket number each have a price stored

I am trying to generate a report based upon a search match on rego number and create a join to the matching tableregister items and list them (with hopefully an end goal of grouping any duplicate items into a qty and subtotal)

This is an access database if that changes the syntax

I am unclear on how I can take the results of one select query and use these results to create a join or there might be a better approach

So I need to firstly locate all receipts with a matching rego number, with those receipts, find the associated items (by docket number) hopefully group the items like so

### receipt no 1

```
Item1 with multiples as qty with subtotal
Item2
Item3
```

### receipt no 2

```
Item1
Item2 with multiples as qty with subtotal
Item3
```

Any help greatly appreciated,

```
(SELECT * from tblreceipts 
where vehicle = 'abc123')
join tblregisterhistory  on 
tblreceipts.docketnum = tblregisterhistory.docketnum
```

I can even get to linking the results from the select query to a join, let alone get to my desired end result.

Comment: you can join the tables inside teh select query `SELECT * from tblreceipts join tblregisterhistory on tblreceipts.docketnum = tblregisterhistory.docketnum where vehicle = 'abc123'`
But I would suggest you learn a bit more about sql first, there are many different websites, just google for it

Comment: Agreed that I have much to learn, I did structure my query as suggested in trial but I am getting syntax error in from clause, which is confusing me further.

Comment: I think with ms-access you have to use `inner join` instead of join

Comment: `SELECT tblregisterhistory.*, tblreceipts.* FROM tblreceipts INNER JOIN tblregisterhistory ON …`. Access query builder should create correct syntax. Do subtotals in report design with Sorting & Grouping features and aggregate calc in textbox.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Comment: The feedback received has helped immensely, and yes access NEEDS the "inner"part of a join statement to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to simply do a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`?  Something like this:

```
select partno, count(*) as qty
from tblreceipts as r inner join 
     tblregisterhistory as rh
     on rh.docketnum = r.docketnum
where r.vehicle = 'abc123'
group by partno;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok with a bit of study and some helpful hints above. I have this (also apologies for the code formatting, still familiarising myself with the stack posting techniques)

```
   SELECT  vehicle, tblregisterhistory.date, partnumber, count(partnumber) as qty, 
    description, sum(price) as subtotal  
    FROM TBLRECEIPTS INNER JOIN 
    tblregisterhistory  ON tblreceipts.docketnumber = 
    tblregisterhistory.docketnumber where tblreceipts.vehicle = 'abc123' group by  
    tblregisterhistory.date, vehicle, partnumber, description, price
```